# Android programming - Multiple choice questionnaire problems

Tags: android, android-activity, radio-button, radio-group, android-toast

I am quite new to Android. I am using Android Studio in order to design a short questionnaire. I have used the Design Mode to create Radio Groups which hold a Text Box for the question and a number of Radio Buttons for the answers as follows:

```
<TextView
            android:text="1) How old are you?"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:id="@+id/q1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="18 - 25 years old"
            android:id="@+id/q1_opt1"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:checked="true" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="26 - 30 years old"
            android:id="@+id/q1_opt2"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/q1_opt1"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:checked="true" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="31 - 40 years old"
            android:id="@+id/q1_opt3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/q1_opt2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:checked="true" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="40  years +"
            android:id="@+id/q1_opt4"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/q1_opt3"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:checked="true" />

    </RadioGroup>
```

I have also added a submit button at the end.

Now my problem is that I would like to give a score according to which option is chosen and generate a total score. In other words, I would like the program to give say, a score of 1 for Option A, a score of 2 for Option B, a score of 3 for Option C, and so on. Then when the user presses the Submit button I would like to output the total score based on all Options chosen.

For example, if user got a score of 2 from choosing Option B from question 1, a score of 3 from choosing Option C from question 2, and a score of 1 from choosing Option A from question 3, I would like to output a Toaster with a Total Score of 6. Well I know how to generate a Toaster and I know how to make a summation of all the scores, however I can't figure out how I can get a score according to which option is chosen when the Submit button is chosen.

I really appreciate any help!

The following is an update showing part of the XML I am using:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".Questionnaire"
android:onClick="returnScore(4)">

<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Questions"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/quest1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:text="1) How old are you?"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:id="@+id/q1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="18 - 25 years old"
        android:id="@+id/q1_opt1"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:clickable="false" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="26 - 30 years old"
        android:id="@+id/q1_opt2"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/q1_opt1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="31 - 40 years old"
        android:id="@+id/q1_opt3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/q1_opt2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="40  years +"
        android:id="@+id/q1_opt4"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/q1_opt3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

</RadioGroup>

    <RadioGroup
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/quest2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/quest1"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/quest1"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="false">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2) What is the highest level of education you have achieved?"
        android:id="@+id/q2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="18dp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Primary school"
        android:id="@+id/q2_opt1" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Secondary School"
        android:id="@+id/q2_opt2" />

    <RadioButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="High School or higher"
        android:id="@+id/q2_opt3" />

</RadioGroup>

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/quest3">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="3) What is you average yearly salary?"
            android:id="@+id/q3"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="10 - 20k"
            android:id="@+id/q3_opt1" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="20 - 40k"
            android:id="@+id/q3_opt2" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="40 - 60k"
            android:id="@+id/q3_opt3" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="60 - 100k"
            android:id="@+id/q3_opt4" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="100k or more"
            android:id="@+id/q3_opt5" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: `a score of 1 for Option A, a score of 2 for Option B, a score of 3 for Option C, ` Strange. I would think that only one choice is ok so only points for one choice. And not always the right answer is on the same radio button i would think. You did not tell how the next quiestion 'comes in'.

Comment: I think that I didn't explain myself well enough. I need a score of 1 for Option A, a score of 2 for Option B, a score of 3 for Option C, etc... because the program isn't exactly a questionnaire. The format is similar to a questionnaire, however I need different scores per option because if for example, the user is more than 40 years old, he will have more experience i.e. a higher score. There is no good or bad answer, but some options might reflect a higher "score". The other questions are of a similar nature.

Comment: Ok. But that was not my only question. In fact it is not even relevant to solve your problem. More important was my last remark but you did not answer that.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what you mean by "how the next question 'comes in'".

Comment: Well i suppose that the user only sees one question at a time. So if he answered a question then how does he go to the next question?

Comment: `android:checked="true" />` You check ALL radiobuttons default to true? Is that even possible? Is it honored?

Comment: At first I tried to make it one question at a time, however I didn't manage and decided to make a number of RadioGroup one after the other all within a ScrollView. I don't know if this is a good approach.

Comment: That you have to decide yourself. Or the user(s). I see nothing here. I don't know how many questions you have so i cannot advise. Are you generating RadioGroups on the fly? Please post the complete radio group layout. Please react to ALL my remarks.

Comment: To be honest, I do not know why I have chosen the option android:checked for all the options. It is a mistake of mine (although Android Studio didn't mark it as an error) and I will remove it because I don't want any option checked by default. Basically when I run the program, only the last option is checked.

Comment: `only the last option is checked.`. That is no good i think. All should be unchecked at start. Please react to ALL my remarks. I have to know how you build up all before i can suggest code how to retrieve all checked buttons.

Comment: Regarding the Radio Buttons, they are not generated on the fly. They are coded one by one in the program. There are 14 of them because I have 14 questions.

Comment: ??? If you have 14 questions you would have 14 RadioGroups and 56 RadioButtons i think.

Comment: I apologise once again. I was referring to RadioGroups. So, let me recap; my program has 14 RadioGroups each with a series of RadioButtons. However the RadioGroups don't have 4 RadioButtons each. Some have more RadioButtons whilst others have less RadioButtons, so I cannot make use of a for ... loop. Also as I told you in a previous comment, I am going to remove the android:checked option, because it was a mistake of mine. P.S. I was trying to post an image of the RadioGroup Layout, however I can't figure out how to post a screenshot.

Comment: You can make use of a for loop even if the number of radiobuttons differ per group. Apparently you had already ideas how to code the summation. Please tell a bit about it. Please post the complete xml. Well not with 14 questions of course. Two questions will do. So we can see the id's.

Comment: I have added the XML code as an update to the question. There are a number of views and layouts within each other (which I think I will have to tackle in the future) because I am not sure which I should be using for my program.

Comment: Ok. Now post your summation code please.

Comment: I haven't written any code for the summation yet because I don't know how I can generate the "score" for each question. However some pseudocode would be as follows: 'for (int i = 0;  i<lastQuestion; i++) { totalScore = totalScore + currentScore[i];} Toast.show(totalScore);'

Comment: You put 14 questions with a number of choices in an xml file. I think you will never do that again as putting all text in a file is easier to maintain. And then you would create the groups on the fly or better yet use a list view. For now you can do it without loop if you just inspect every radio button. int score =0: if (rb1.isChecked()) score+=1; if (rb2.isChecked()) score +=2: and so on for all radio buttons.